# Removing iPhone 12 imei from carrier blacklist

Tags: iphone

So recently, I got an iPhone 12 mini from T-Mobile, but after using it for a bit, I was not able to use any features of my network. Upon contacting T-Mobile about this, they said that they goofed up and improperly recorded which iPhone they had sent me. They said they marked the one they sent me as lost/stolen, and evidentially, they can't undo that or something. Long story short, they sent
me a new working iPhone and said I could just keep the other one that was marked as lost/stolen. Physically, it is a perfectly working brand new iPhone. I've done some research and found out that when a device is marked as lost/stolen, T-Mobile places it's IMEI on a blacklist.
I am wondering if there is a way to fix this second iPhone so I can give it to my son. There are a few websites that claim to be able to remove the IMEI from the carrier blacklist for $100 or so, but they all look kind of sketchy, so I'm hesitant about using one of those. Does anybody know of a legit way/service to fix this iPhone?

Comment: How do you expect the the problem with your first iPhone to be resolved legitimately if T-Mobile has already told you it is marked as lost or stolen?

Answer (score 3):

There is not.  If there were, TMobile would simply have done so.